# vuejs <select-vue> does not work with null values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

select.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="relative">
    <label
      :for="$attrs.name"
      class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
      >{{ $t($attrs.label) }} {{ required ? '*' : '' }}</label
    >
    <i
      v-if="!disabled"
      class="fa-light absolute right-3 top-11 fa-chevron-down"
    ></i>
    <select
      @input="changed"
      :value="value"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :class="errorInputStyle"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      class="mt-2 appearance-none disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-gray-100 outline-none disabled:text-gray-600 disabled:ring-gray-200 bg-white block shadow w-full rounded-md border-0 py-2 pl-3 pr-10 ring-1 ring-inset focus:ring-2 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
    >
      <option :selected="value === defaultValue" :value="defaultValue" disabled>
        {{ $t($attrs.placeholder) || 'Bitte auswählen' }}
      </option>
      <option
        :selected="option.value === value"
        :value="option.value"
        v-for="option in options"
      >
        {{ $t(option.text) }}
      </option>
    </select>

    <p :class="errorDescriptionStyle" class="mt-2 text-sm">
      {{ $t($attrs.description) }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { BaseOptionT } from '~/types'

export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      default: '',
    },
    options: {
      default: () => [] as BaseOptionT[],
    },
    required: {
      default: false,
    },

    disabled: {
      default: false,
    },
    isError: {
      default: false,
    },
  },

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    let selectValue = ref('')
    let defaultValue = ref()
    function changed(e: any) {
      let target = e.target as HTMLSelectElement

      try {
        return emit('input', JSON.parse(target.value))
      } catch (err) {
        return emit('input', target.value)
      }
    }
    let errorDescriptionStyle = computed(() => [
      props.isError ? 'text-red-500' : 'text-gray-500',
    ])
    onMounted(() => {
      if (!props.options.some((o) => o.value === props.value)) {
        defaultValue.value = props.value
      }
    })
    let errorInputStyle = computed(() => [
      props.isError
        ? 'text-red-900 ring-red-300 placeholder:text-red-300  focus:ring-red-600'
        : 'text-gray-900 ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-300  focus:ring-green-600',
    ])
    return {
      changed,
      defaultValue,
      selectValue,
      errorDescriptionStyle,
      errorInputStyle,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is the problem:

```
<select-vue v-model="group.billing_waiting_period" :options="billWaitingPeriods" />
```

When i use my component like this, and in this case `billing_waiting_period` exist but has value `null` inside of it, vue does not update my UI when i select something else from the dropdown. The `group` object is an prop

Here is the rest:

```
    let billWaitingPeriods = computed(() =>
      Object.values(BillWaitingPeriod).map((interval) => {
        switch (interval) {
          case BillWaitingPeriod.ONE_MONTH:
            return { value: interval, text: '1 Monat' }
          case BillWaitingPeriod.TWO_MONTH:
            return { value: interval, text: '2 Monate' }
          case BillWaitingPeriod.THREE_MONTH:
            return { value: interval, text: '3 Monate' }
          default:
            return { value: interval, text: '1 Monat' }
        }
      })
    )

export enum BillWaitingPeriod {
  ONE_MONTH = "ONE_MONTH",
  TWO_MONTH = "TWO_MONTH",
  THREE_MONTH = "THREE_MONTH"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

never change `prop` in vue! i see you are trying to change 1 property of 1 prop this is not allowed and it won't work instead you need 1 emit event

```
const billing_waiting_period = computed({
  get: () => group.billing_waiting_period,
  set: val => emit("update:group.billing_waiting_period", val)
})
```